# bashrc script not accepting space in directory name

Tags: bash

I have added a variable at the end of my `~/.basrc` file :

```
export xyz = /home/faizal/DEV/ADT workspace/xyz
```

But if i open a new terminal, i get the error :

```
bash: export: 'workspace/xyz': not a valid identifier
```

So i try a variety of alternatives :

```
export xyz=/home/faizal/DEV/ADT\ workspace/xyz
export xyz="/home/faizal/DEV/ADT workspace/xyz"
export xyz="/home/faizal/DEV/ADT\ workspace/xyz"
export xyz='/home/faizal/DEV/ADT workspace/xyz'
export xyz='/home/faizal/DEV/ADT\ workspace/xyz'
```

They all give me the error when i try `cd $xyz`:

```
bash: cd: /home/faizal/DEV/ADT: No such file or directory
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `.bashrc` :

```
export xyz="/home/faizal/DEV/ADT workspace/xyz"
```

Use this to access it :

```
cd "$xyz"
```